# Can we return SqlDataReader OR DataTable from WCF method

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF.I have one doubt regarding returning data from WCF method.

Can we return SqlDataReader OR DataTable object from WCF method?

thanks

Comment: You *can* - but that doesn't mean you *should*! WCF is geared towards returning **concrete objects** (or collection of objects) - you should not use `DataTable` (huge overhead, .NET specific) and most definitely not `SqlDataReader` (open connection, transferred over WCF)

Comment: WCF service should be totally independent from the caller - so *connecting* the caller to the service by returning an open connection using a `SqlDataReader` is a **horribly bad idea**.... don't do it..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but a DataTable has a lot of overhead, you might think about writing it to a list of entities and pass this list

It caused me much less troubles this way

Comment: OK i agree returning DataTable OR SqlDataReader is a bad practice but if we can could you please tell me how can we return just for knowledge

Comment: As with any function: public DataTable GetMyData() { return new DataTable}

Comment: I did the same but getting following error: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Comment: Ok, I think this happens by passing the SQLDataReader?! This only exists as long as you keep your connection open (as mark_s wrote)! So you would need to keep your connection in a loop for Example! But i have to say, I never tried this, so it might be, the connection won't be passed with the SQLDataReader overall

Comment: Actually that error comes when i have through the public DataTable GetMyData() { return new DataTable} approach and working properly if i do public DataSet GetMyData() { return new DataSet} approach. why?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new object, then return a collection of those. Something like this.

```
public class Thing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then with your datatable/reader, you can use LINQ or iteration to create a collection:

Rough sudo-code:

```
Initialise List for Thing

foreach var v in DataTable
{
    List<Thing>.Add(new Thing(){ ID = v.ID, Name = v.Name });
}

return List
```

Alternatively, you can use linq:

```
List<Thing> theList = DataTable.Select(x => new Thing { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name });

return theList;
```

You can figure the rest out, I'm sure, if you need more clarification I will expand on my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 100% u can return with any returntype supported by .net. But only thing is WCF is very flexible so the client of WCF is not 100% .net framework always. It can be consume by java also. and java returntype is not 100% equivalent to .net returntype so u need to take care about it. 
e.g generic lists are converted in observable collection by default at client side.